# Invalid Cast Exception while rendering Orchard part in "editor" context

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, orchardcms

I made a DateTime part in Orchard, and when I try to edit the type that contains this DateTime part, I get the following exception. Below the exception is the code from cshtml file that is used for rendering part in the editor. Type of datetime is System.DateTime. The thing is that I get this exception sometimes, and sometimes it works perfectly, and I couldn't find any reason for getting this exception, like it is totally random.

System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

```
@model DateTimeP.Models.DateTimePart

<fieldset class="edit-datetime">
    <legend>Datum i vreme događaja:</legend>
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.datetime)
</fieldset>
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem, because it's been bugging me for some time?

Comment: Can you post the code for your DateTimePart?

Comment: Of Course, here's the code:
'code(using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Orchard.ContentManagement;
using Orchard.ContentManagement.Records;

namespace DateTimeP.Models
{
    public class DateTimePart : ContentPart<DateTimeRecord>
    {
        [Required]
        public System.DateTime datetime
        {
            get { return Record.datetime;}
            set { Record.datetime = value; }
        }

    }
})

Comment: But the thing is that i tried to delete my DateTime part module from Orchard, delete the record for my DateTime part from Orchard_Framework_DataMigrationRecord table, delete all tables that my part generated, and after that I installed whole part again, updated it in Module Manager in Orchard, and now everything is working, though I still don't know what the problem was.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should reuse existing modules for that:

https://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Contrib.DateTimeField

Comment: I initially wanted to use this, but this module is a field and I needed a part because I wanted it to be persisted in the database, for making some queries later. I also tried Projector module, but couldn't install it (the installation was sucessfull, I enabled it, but the icon in the menu just didn't want to show up), so I ended up with writing my own module, now it works fine, I didn't change the code, just reinstalled it.
Anyway, thanks for support!